# Is there a possibility for a segmentation of a 3d-np.array (boolean variables)

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, boolean, image-segmentation

I have a 3D-numpy-array which is exclusively filled with boolean variables (True/False).
Is there a possibility or library that implements a segmentation of all entries with "True" in the N6 neighbourhood? In my research, I unfortunately only found something for image processing with openCV.

The goal would then be an array in which all connected "True" entries are provided with the same number (assignment of the segment). Alternatively, a separate array would also work for each individual segment, in which only the elements belonging to the respective segment are "true".

I would be very grateful for suggestions and tips.

EDIT:
This would be a Input-Array:

```
[[[ True  True False False  True]
  [False False False False False]
  [False False False False False]
  [False False  True False False]
  [False False  True  True False]]

 [[ True  True False False  True]
  [False  True False False False]
  [False False False False False]
  [False False False False False]
  [False False  True False False]]

 [[False False False False False]
  [False False False False False]
  [False False  True False False]
  [False False False False False]
  [False False False False False]]

 [[False False False False  True]
  [False False False False False]
  [False False False False False]
  [False False False  True  True]
  [False False False  True  True]]

 [[False False False False  True]
  [False False False False  True]
  [False False False False False]
  [False False False  True  True]
  [False False False  True  True]]]
```

As picture this would look this (with numbering of individual segment):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAPGJ.png)

Than i need a segmentation (without knowing in advance, how many segments will be in the array). The first output array will look like this:

```
[[[ True,  True, False, False,  False],
  [False, False, False, False, False],
  [False, False, False, False, False],
  [False, False,  False, False, False],
  [False, False,  False,  False, False]],

  [[ True,  True, False, False,  False],
  [False,  True, False, False, False], ...(rest is False)
```

The second array for the second segment looks like this:

```
[[[ False,  False, False, False,  True],
[False, False, False, False, False],
[False, False, False, False, False],
[False, False,  False, False, False],
[False, False,  False,  False, False]],

[[ False,  False, False, False,  True],
 [False,  False, False, False, False], ...(rest is False)
```

and so on, till all segments are determined

Comment: You are going to have to provide an example input and output for this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and your note. I will edit the question and provide input and output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems common for me to answer my own questions:

Following library is necessary:

[connected-components-3d](https://pypi.org/project/connected-components-3d/#description)

My Code:

```
import cc3d
connectivity = 6 #18, 26
labels_out = cc3d.connected_components(pic_3d, connectivity=connectivity)
```

works with boolean-arrays

the result:

```
[[[1 1 0 0 2]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 3 0 0]
  [0 0 3 3 0]]

 [[1 1 0 0 2]
  [0 1 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 3 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 4 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0 5]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 6 6]
  [0 0 0 6 6]]

 [[0 0 0 0 5]
  [0 0 0 0 5]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 6 6]
  [0 0 0 6 6]]]
```

After this i can get my required (separate) arrays with simple loops!

Hopefully it helps someone!